# Close "Open Action Center" dialog popup

Tags: windows-7, security-center

Below is a dialog box that popped up while working.  How do I close it?  I clicked on Open Action Center, but this one didn't go away.  Other than:

- turning on Security Center service
- setting up a backup
- rebooting

is there a real way to close this?

(I'm looking for how to close it right now, not prevent it from coming up.)

[image: alt t3xt]

Comment: you mean tuning off only the popup as it don't close when clicking elsewhere? Close the Action Centre program? or turn off notification about security centre?

Comment: I just need to get rid of the current popup.  Clicking outside or opening up Action Center do not get rid of it.  It's still stuck here.

Comment: Click on the "flag icon" in notification area don't work either I guess?

Comment: Yeah, just tried it.  Still there.

Comment: If this is truly a one-time glitch, you might just restart the security center service. (cue moss "have you tried turning it off and on again?")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable specific alerts from appearing in the popup, which effectively stops the popup from appearing at all if there are no alerts to display.

Go into **Control Panel**, into the **Action Center** and click the link on the left to **Change Action Center settings**.  Untick the **Windows Backup** option.

[image]

If it does not immediately disappear after applying the settings, try killing the explorer.exe process from Task Manager and start the explorer.exe process again (in the Windows Task Manager, select File -> New Task (Run) and type in explorer.exe).

Comment: Should have explained, unticking one of the active alerts should give it a nudge, cause it to refresh and vanish.. in theory.

Comment: Ahhh freedom.  Killing explorer also got rid of the start menu, so I had to use the "New Task" button under Task Manager to restart Explorer.exe, but that did it.

Comment: I did untick all of them and it updated the popup, but it still didn't go away, but killing explorer got it.

Comment: Kill explorer and re-start should be the first thing to do; then cave in to the troubleshooting centre configuration if that fails.

Answer (score 11):

Try these steps:

1. open Task Manager
2. end the explorer.exe process
3. click anywhere in this popup
4. open Task Manager again
5. go to File → New Task (Run...)
6. enter `explorer.exe` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>